# Validacion con form request en tabla pivote laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

Como puedo ocupar un form request en tablas pivotes para validar, ya que éstas tablas pivotes no tienen ni controlador, ni modelo.
Tengo un controlador el cual es el encargado de hacer el attach a la tabla pivote y también de insertar las columnas extras.
Tengo un form request de ese controlador, pero sólo funciona con los campos de la tabla asociada al controlador.
[image: Vista]

Form Request:

```
<?php namespace SIA\Http\Requests;

use SIA\Http\Requests\Request;


 class VentaRequest extends Request {


/**
 * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}



/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'msocod_id' => 'required',
        'mclcod_id' => 'required',
        'msucod_id' => 'required',
        'tvtcod_id' => 'required',
        'mdccod_id' => 'required',
        'vtfedc'    => 'date_format:d-m-Y|required',
        'vtnfecn'   => 'date_format:d-m-Y|required',
        'concod_id' => 'required',


    ];




  }

}
```

Controlador metodo store:

```
public function store(VentaRequest $request) 
{


        try{        



        //Obtener el Codigo de documento        
        $doc = $request->mdccod_id;

        //Rescatar codigo de impuesto
        $mim = M_DCVT::Docu($doc);
        $mim = $mim->mimpcd_id;         

        //Rescatar clave de contabilización de documento
        $clave = M_DCVT::Docu($doc);
        $clave = $clave->mdccvc;

            //Rescatar sociedad
        $soci = $request->msocod_id;
            //Rescatar codigo de impuesto (C1)
        $codim = M_IMPT::Codigo($doc);
        $codim = $codim->mimpcd;

            //Rescatar cuenta contable de impuesto
        $ccim = M_IMPT::Iva($soci, $codim);
        $ccim = $ccim->mpccct;

        //Rescatar clave de contabilizacion de impuesto
        $cvc = M_IMPT::Iva($soci, $codim);
        $cvc = $cvc->mimcvc;

        // id del cliente
        $ccli = $request->mclcod_id;
            //Obtener el codigo del cliente
        $mclie = M_CLIE::CodigoCli($ccli);
        $mclie = $mclie->mclcod;

            //Buscar la clave de contabilizacion del cliente
            $clien = M_CLIE::Clave($soci, $mclie);      
            $clien = $clien->mclvcc;

            $clien2 = M_CLIE::Clave($soci, $mclie);
            $clien2 = $clien2->mpccct;

            $mone = M_SOCI::Moneda($soci);
            $mone = $mone->moncod_id;


            //Obtener fecha y guardsarlas en la base de datos
            $fecha = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $request->vtfedc)->Format('Y-m-d');
            $fechac = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $request->vtnfecn)->Format('Y-m-d');

            //tipo cliente para cuenta de ingresos
            $tpcl = M_CLIE::TipoCli($soci, $mclie);

            //Rescatar el arreglo de ids de los materiales
            $material = $request->input('mmscod_id',[]);



            //Rescatar codigo grupo imputacion material
            $impmate = M_MTSV::Imputacion($material, $soci);

            //Variable para rescatar cuenta ingreso de la tabla dt_ctin
            $dcingre = [];
            //Rescate de la cuenta de ingreso
            $dcingre = DT_CTIN::CodImpMat($material,$soci,$tpcl,$impmate);
            //dd($dcingre);


            //Capturar cantidad de cada producto en un arreglo      
            $cant = $request->input('vtcanp',[]);
            //Capturar precio de cada producto en un arreglo
            $prec = $request->input('vtprep',[]);









            $attach = [];


            foreach ($material as $k=>$id){
                $attach[$id] = [];



                // Agregar el arreglo quantity en la variable attach segun su relacion con el id del producto
                if(array_key_exists($k, $cant)){
                    $attach[$id]['vtcanp'] = $cant[$k];

                }

                // Agregar el arreglo price en la variable attach segun su relacion con el id del producto
                if(array_key_exists($k, $prec)){
                    $attach[$id]['vtprep'] = $prec[$k];


                }

                //Campo de numero rescatado de la base de datos desde otra funcion. El numero es un campo asociado al producto, el cual 
                // se ingresa automaticamente y es asociado a un solo producto en particular
                if(array_key_exists($k, $dcingre)){
                   $attach[$id]['vtccin'] = $dcingre[$k];

                }
            //Ids de los productos
                if(empty($attach[$id])){
                    $attach[$id] = $id;
                }
            }
                    $pedido = PV_VTA::create([          
                'msocod_id' => $request->msocod_id,
                'tvtcod_id' => $request->tvtcod_id,
                'stpvcd_id' => 1
                ]);




            $documento = VT_DOC::create([
                    'msocod_id' =>$request->msocod_id,
                    'vtndoc' =>$request->vtndoc,
                    'mclcod_id' =>$request->mclcod_id,
                    'msucod_id' =>$request->msucod_id,
                    'tvtcod_id' =>$request->tvtcod_id,
                    'mdccod_id' =>$request->mdccod_id,  
                    'moncod_id' =>$mone,
                    'pvnped'=>$pedido->pvnped,                          
                    'vtfedc' =>$fecha,
                    'vtnfecn' =>$fechac,
                    'concod_id' =>$request->concod_id,
                    'vtpjds' =>$request->vtpjds,
                    'mimpcd_id' => $mim,
                    'mdccvc' =>$clave,
                    'vtccim' =>$ccim,
                    'mimcvc' =>$cvc,
                    'mclvcc' =>$clien,
                    'vtpcon' =>$request->mes,
                    'vtacon' =>$request->anno,
                    'vtcccli'=>$clien2
                ]); 




           } catch(\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e){
                $tt = $e->errorInfo[1];


                if ($e instanceof\PDOException) {                   

                switch ($tt) {
                    case 1452:
                    Session::flash('message', 'Error ');
                    return Redirect::to('/venta/create');
                    break;

                }
             }



        }

             $documento->m_mtsv()->attach($attach);  

        Session::flash('message', 'Documento creado correctamente');
        return Redirect::to('/venta'); 


 }
```

Modelo Venta:

```
<?php namespace SIA;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use DB;

class VT_DOC extends Model {

protected $table = 'vt_doc';

protected $primaryKey='vtnrin';
public $timestamps=false;
protected $fillable = [columnas,columnas,etc.]; 

  public function m_mtsv(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('SIA\M_MTSV',
'mmtsv_vtdoc','vtnrin','mmscod_id','mmsnam','vtcanp','vtprep','vtccin')-    >withPivot('mmscod_id','vtcanp','vtprep');
 }
}
```

Migracion de tabla pivote

```
<?php

  use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
  use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

  class CreateM_mtsvVt_docPivotTable extends Migration
 {
  /**
   * Run the migrations.
   *
   * @return void
   */
   public function up()
   {
    Schema::create('m_mtsv_vt_doc', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('mmscod_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('mmscod_id')->references('id')->on('m_mtsv')-       >onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('vtnrin')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('vtnrin')->references('vtnrin')->on('vt_doc')->onDelete('cascade');
       $table->decimal('vtcanp',8,0)->unsigned();
        $table->double('vtprep',10,2)->unsigned();

    });
  }

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
 public function down()
 {
    Schema::drop('m_mtsv_vt_doc');
 }
}
```

codigo vista

```
<h2> Documento venta Prueba</h2> <br/>

  <div class="panel panel-default">

            <div class="panel-body">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="sociedad" class="control-label">Sociedad</label>

                        <input type="hidden" name="hidden" id="hidden">
                        <input type="hidden" name="mes" id="mes">
                        <input type="hidden" name="anno" id="anno"> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">                          
                        <div class="form-group">

                                {!!Form::select('msocod_id',['' => '- Seleccione una sociedad -'] +$soci,null, ['class' => 'form-control','id'=>'msocod_id', 'name'=>'msocod_id'])!!}   

                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="form-group">                                    

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="fecha" class="control-label">Nº Documento</label>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">                                
                            {!!Form::text('vtndoc', null,['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'ingrese num'])!!}    
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="socio" class="control-label">Cliente</label>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                                {!!Form::select('mclcod_id',['' => '- Seleccione un cliente -'] +$cli,null, ['class' => 'form-control'])!!} 
                        </div>
                    </div>                  
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="colonia" class="control-label">Sucursal</label>&nbsp;

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group" id="sucu">
                            {!!Form::select('msucod_id',['' => '- Seleccione una sucursal -'] +$sucu,null, ['class' => 'form-control'])!!}  
                        </div>
                    </div>                      
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="tipo" class="control-label">Tipo venta</label>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                                {!!Form::select('tvtcod_id',['' => '- Seleccione una sucursal -'] +$tventa,null, ['class' => 'form-control'])!!}    
                        </div>
                    </div>                                          
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="tipo" class="control-label">Clase Docto</label>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                                {!!Form::select('mdccod_id',['' => '- Seleccione una clase -'] +$doc,null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id'=> 'mdccod_id', 'name'=>'mdccod_id'])!!} 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">



                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <div class="form-group">


                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">


                        </div>
                    </div>                                          
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="tipo" class="control-label">Fecha Docto</label>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3" width="20%">
                        <div class="form-group">
                                <!--{!!Form::date('vtfedc', null,['class'=>'form-control'])!!}  -->
                                {!!Form::text('vtfedc', null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'id' => 'vtfedc','name'=>'vtfedc' ,'placeholder'=>'dd-mm-aaaa','data-error'=> 'Please enter name field.'])!!}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="tipo" class="control-label">Fecha Docto</label>                 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                                <!--{!!Form::date('vtnfecn', null,['class'=>'form-control'])!!}-->  
                                {!!Form::text('vtnfecn', null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'id' => 'vtnfecn','name'=>'vtnfecn', 'placeholder'=>'dd-mm-aaaa'])!!}                      
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <div class="form-group">


                        </div>
                    </div>
                -->
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <div class="form-group">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">


                        </div>
                    </div>                                          
                </div>              
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="tipo" class="control-label">Condición pago</label>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                                {!!Form::select('concod_id',['' => '- Seleccione una condicion -'] +$condi,null, ['class' => 'form-control'])!!}    
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">                                    

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="fecha" class="control-label">% Descuento</label>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">                                
                            {!!Form::text('vtpjds', null,['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'ingrese num', 'id' => 'vtpjds', 'name' => 'vtpjds'])!!}  
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <hr>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12" id="columna">
                        <table class="table table-hover table-condensed responsive" id="tabla">
                            <thead>
                                <tr><th></th>                                   
                                    <th>Codigo Art./servicios</th>
                                    <th>Descricpión Art./servicios</th>
                                    <th>Cantidad</th>
                                    <th>Precio</th>
                                    <th>Valor neto</th>                                     
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody id="tbo">
                                <tr id="tr_1">
                                    <td width="4%" class="text-center"><a id="eliminarLinea"  ><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></a>
                                    </td>                           
                                    <td width="23%">
                                        {!!Form::select('mmscod_id[]',['' => '- Seleccione un material -'] +$mat,null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id'=>'mmscod_id'])!!}
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="20%">
                                        {!!Form::text('descripcion',null, ['class' =>'form-control','id'=>'descripcion' ,'disabled'=>'disabled'])!!}
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="17%">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cantidad" name="vtcanp[]"/> 

                                    </td>
                                    <td width="17%">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="precio" name="vtprep[]"/>

                                    </td>
                                    <td width="22%">
                                        {!!Form::text('condes', null,['class'=>'form-control', 'id'=>'valorn', 'name'=>'valorn', 'disabled'=>'disabled'])!!}                                            
                                    </td>                       
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>                                
                        </table>

                        <a  class="btn btn-primary" id="addRow"><i class="entypo-plus"></i>Agregar linea</a>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <hr>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <table class="table table-hover table-condensed" id="tabla">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>

                                    <th>Total neto</th>
                                    <th>Valor descuento</th>
                                    <th>Monto neto</th>
                                    <th>IVA</th>
                                    <th>Monto total</th>                                        
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr id="tr1">

                                    <td width="20%"><input type="text" class="form-control total" id="total" name="total"></td>
                                    <td width="25%"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="vadesc" name="vadesc" onkeyup="articulo(this);" ></td>
                                    <td width="20%"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="neto" name="neto" ></td>
                                    <td width="20%"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="iva" name="iva" value="" ></td>
                                    <td width="20%"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="montotal" name="montotal" onkeyup="importe(this);" ></td>

                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>

                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>                  
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-9"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block btn-icon">Generar / Guardar<i class="entypo-check"></i></button>

                                                </div>  
                </div>  
            </div>      
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
            <br />

        </div>  
    </div>
```

[image: Error package 1]

[image: Error package 2]

Comment: ¿Qué necesitas validar exactamente? Muéstranos un ejemplo.

Comment: Hola. Adjunte una imagen en la pregunta. La idea es validar las posiciones del documento, o sea la parte en la cual uno agrega lineas de pedido y son 3 campos: codigo art/servicios, cantidad y precio.
Esos campos necesito validar y como se ve en la imagen los asociados al controlador se validan los otros no

Comment: Tendría que ver algo de código para entender lo que pretendes hacer, solo con la imagen no logro hacerme la idea.

Comment: En la pregunta puse algunas cosas...no se si necesitaras algo mas. Estaré atento, muchas gracias

Comment: Hola..añadí la migración de la tabla pivote en el cual los campos que quiero validar son: mmscod_id, vtcanp y vtprep.

Comment: Ya empiezo a entender, ahora ¿qué te impide validarlos? o ¿qué tipo de validación quieres para cada uno de los 3 campos? La validación está atada al Request, por ende no depende que los datos estén en uno u otro modelo/tabla.

Comment: Quiero hacer la validación con la clase request que tengo hecha (VentaRequest) y que se asocia al controlador en el método store. Eso no me ha resultado

Comment: aún así no respondiste la pregunta, qué tipo de validación quieres hacer con esos tres campos? required, min, max, etc... ?

Comment: ahh perdón, me gustará que fuera required, min, max y quizás si surge otra puede ser unique

Comment: ¿Qué pasa cuando incluyes `'mmscod_id' => 'required',` en las reglas de validación? ¿Qué mensaje de error aparece?

Comment: No sale nada, ni mensaje de error ni de validación. Es como en la foto que puse en mi pregunta.

Comment: Listo, edite la pregunta agregando el código de la vista.

Comment: He intentado haciendo otras cosas pero no funciona :( 
Alguna idea?

Comment: Esta noche reviso todo el código y hago un intento.

Comment: Gracias, estaré atento.

Comment: En el código de la vista que has publicado aquí no se ve la etiqueta de apertura del formulario.

Comment: Hola, eso es porque tengo el código separado.
Mira:
@extends('layouts.principal')
@section('content')

include('alerts.request')
include('alerts.error')
{!!Form::open(['route'=>'venta.store', 'id'=>'form', 'method'=>'POST'])!!} 

include('venta.forms.venta')

{!!Form::close()!!}

section('script')
{!!Html::script('js/script.js')!!}

stop

stop
Tuve que sacar algunos '@' no es que no los tenga, solo que en la publicación no me dejó

Comment: EL problema por lo que veo es el package que instale en laravel, el cual es: proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation, que re-usa los form request de laravel o el metodo validator para validar los forms automaticamente  a client-side. Entonces al momento de hacer un for each en la clase request para recorrer un array para validarlo, me da un error.
Si alguien sabe como hacerlo con este package sería de gran ayuda...en mi pregunta pondré el error que me arroja