# Impedir eliminar un elemento si es que existe en una tabla o más laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

Necesito orientación para saber como validar un elemento creado que este presente en varias tablas no se pueda eliminar advirtiendo que se encuentra relacionado a éstas tablas.
Por ejemplo tengo una tabla (M_MONE), la cual esta relacionada a 3 tablas.
Tengo un crud, el cual puedo editar información de mi tabla mencionada (M_MONE), el cual tiene un botón de actualizar y eliminar, entonces es ahi donde quiero que en dicho elemento se quiera eliminar y este presente en estas tablas, me impida hacerlo.

Comment: Es esta misma pregunta? http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/23730/validacion-con-form-request-en-tabla-pivote-laravel-5

Comment: No, no es la misma pregunta, ya que la otra no pregunto sobre si existe un elemento en otras tablas y que me impida eliminarlo

Comment: Es el mismo codigo, pero esta es otra pregunta

Comment: Por favor si alguien puede ayudarme, se lo agradecería bastante

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema pero estoy utilizando Laravel 8.
Con respecto a la solución propuesta por Andres Gómez, trate de adaptarlo y me sale lo siguiente. ErrorException
Trying to get property '' of non-object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Voy a asumir que tienes modelos y relaciones.

Puedes hacer una comprobación como esta en el método de tu controlador.

Es muy sencilla y si la vas a usar mucho puedes hacerla una función para reutilizarla.

```
public function update(Request $request){
  $m_mone=M_MONE::find($request->id);
  $count=0;
  $count+=count($m_mone->tabla1);
  $count+=count($m_mone->tabla2);
  $count+=count($m_mone->tabla3);
  if($count>0){
     return ['msg'=>'Elemento en uso'];
  }else{
     $m_mone->fill($request->all());
     $m_mone->save();
     return $m_mone;
  }
}
```

Comment: Gracias, intentare hacerlo y te comento

Comment: Muchas gracias Ernesto, me ayudo tu respuesta un montón.
Saludos!!

Answer (score 1):

Estimado, si estas usando una base de datos relacional como es por ejemplo MySQL eso se soluciona con una foreign key constraint, no tienes que programar nada, solo capturar si la sentencia de delete te devuelve error y nada mas.

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero al momento de hacer eliminacion en mi UI no arroja error, solo se elimina.